# c++: what is this convertion using with a &?

Tags: c++

```
class base {};

class derive: public base {};

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<derive> d1;
    std::unique_ptr<base> b1;

    //d1 = std::move((std::unique_ptr<derive>)(b1)); // 1. fail
    d1 = std::move((std::unique_ptr<derive>&)(b1)); //   2. why can this works?
return 0;
}
```

show as the code, we use c-style forcing convertion in order to convert `std::unique_ptr<base>` into `std::unique_ptr<derive>` then fail, while it works with adding a '&', what is that mean?

`1` shows the compile error: `E0312 no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::unique_ptr<base, std::default_delete<base>>" to "std::unique_ptr<derive, std::default_delete<derive>>" exists`
`

Comment: i cannot spot any difference between 1 and 2

Comment: and please include the error message in the quesiton. What does it mean "then failed" ?

Comment: if you ask me a c-style cast is never correct, you can forget that they exist

Comment: The only difference I see on the "1. failed" line is that the beginning of the line begins with a `//`, which means it is a comment. The "2 why can this works?" line relies on **undefined behavior**, so "works" is suspect.

Comment: sorry for forgetting to remove `&` in `1`

Comment: Undefined behaviour sometimes appears to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: strictly speaking, it doesn't work, it causes a compiler warning: `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]` [online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0656b6209f04faf)

Answer (score 0):

In order to cast std::unique_ptr of a Base class to std::unique_ptr of a Derived class you can use the [approach proposed by Igor Tandetnik](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1aecdb8a-6899-46ed-99fb-88bd81520f99/how-to-cast-a-uniqueptr-from-base-class-to-derived-class) (Such cast is only possible if `b1` is pointing to an instance of the Derived class):

```
d1 = std::unique_ptr<derive>(static_cast<derive*>(b1.release()));
```

([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68c3737ee5982396))